# как вернуть дефолтные настройки в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

как вернуть дефолтные настройки в phpstorm?

Comment: phpstorm под рукой нет, но по идее должно быть аналогично idea: File -> Manate IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults

Comment: * Manage IDE Settings

Answer (score 0):

В меню выбрать File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings